# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method Context.Set<>

Tags: linq, entity-framework-5

So out of the blue, an application (WPF, MVVM) is throwing an exception when performing a linq query. This query is performed in two different views but is character-for-character exactly the same. Only one view throws and exception.

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1[DQSA.Entities.DrugScan] SetDrugScan' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

The query is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Linq.Dynamic;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

//....

var contents = (from i in ctx.Set<Entities.ToteContents>()
                                    where i.ToteID == ToteID
                                    group i by i.Drug into g
                                    select new
                                    {
                                        Drug = g.Key,
                                        QtyShipped = g.Sum(x => x.Qty),
                                        QtyScanned = (ctx.Set<Entities.DrugScan>()
                                        .Where(x => x.ToteID == ToteID && x.DrugID == g.Key.DrugID)
                                        .Count())
                                    }).ToList();
```

The working view renders a PDF report using this data with no problem.  It's in the same project as the non-working view and the `#includes` are the same as well. So I am at a loss to explain the issue.``

Comment: EF cannot translate the `ctx.Set().Where` into SQL - you'll need to either add that total outside of the EF query or use a join to get the sum.

Comment: What he said.  I think if you pull it out into its own variable, it might work.  `var foo = ctx.Set<Entities.DrugScan>().Where(x => x.ToteID == ToteID && x.DrugID == g.Key.DrugID);` then `QtyScanned = foo.Count()`

Comment: @Will  I doubt it.  You're just encapsulating the query into a variable `foo`.  EF won't be able to translate that to SQL any better than in-lining it.

Comment: @DStanley Yeah, encapsulating it into an IQueryable, which it might be able to handle.  I can't test that out, but I'm 80% sure it will work.

Comment: I understand what you guys are saying, but that exact same query works correctly on another view. Why would it translate in one instance and not another?